# Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, abntex2

I formatted my PC and then installed MikTeX and TexStudio. Now I can't compile my code. The error that appears is:

```
Package ifluatex Error: Name clash, \ifluatex is already defined }
```

Before formatting the PC everything was compiling, I don't know what else to do. I cleared my code and the same error still appears.

```
 \documentclass[12pt,a4paper, oneside, hidelinks]{abntex2}

\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{leading}   
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage[footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts, amstext}
    \usepackage{color} 
    \usepackage{listings} 
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[bottom=2cm,top=3cm,left=3cm,right=2cm, headheight=17pt ]{geometry} 
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} 
    \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} 
    \usepackage{lastpage}
    \usepackage{multirow} 
    \usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite} 
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{titlesec } 
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}


    \autor{xx }
    \titulo{xx}
    \local{xx}
    \data{xx}
    \preambulo{xxx}
    \tipotrabalho{xx}

    \begin{document}

    Hello

    \end{document}
```

The error is defined on line 174 of the file log file as illustrated in the figure below:

[image]

The complete file of "log file ifluatex.sty" follows below.

```
        %%
    %% This is file `ifluatex.sty',
    %% generated with the docstrip utility.
    %%
    %% The original source files were:
    %%
    %% ifluatex.dtx  (with options: `package')
    %% 
    %% This is a generated file.
    %% 
    %% Project: ifluatex
    %% Version: 2016/05/16 v1.4
    %% 
    %% Copyright (C) 2007, 2009, 2010 by
    %%    Heiko Oberdiek <heiko.oberdiek at googlemail.com>
    %% 
    %% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
    %% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
    %% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any later
    %% version. This version of this license is in
    %%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/lppl-1-3c.txt
    %% and the latest version of this license is in
    %%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
    %% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of
    %% LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
    %% 
    %% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
    %% 
    %% This Current Maintainer of this work is Heiko Oberdiek.
    %% 
    %% The Base Interpreter refers to any `TeX-Format',
    %% because some files are installed in TDS:tex/generic//.
    %% 
    %% This work consists of the main source file ifluatex.dtx
    %% and the derived files
    %%    ifluatex.sty, ifluatex.pdf, ifluatex.ins, ifluatex.drv,
    %%    ifluatex-test1.tex, ifluatex-test2.tex, ifluatex-test3.tex.
    %% 
    \begingroup\catcode61\catcode48\catcode32=10\relax%
      \catcode13=5 % ^^M
      \endlinechar=13 %
      \catcode35=6 % #
      \catcode39=12 % '
      \catcode44=12 % ,
      \catcode45=12 % -
      \catcode46=12 % .
      \catcode58=12 % :
      \catcode64=11 % @
      \catcode123=1 % {
      \catcode125=2 % }
      \expandafter\let\expandafter\x\csname ver@ifluatex.sty\endcsname
      \ifx\x\relax % plain-TeX, first loading
      \else
        \def\empty{}%
        \ifx\x\empty % LaTeX, first loading,
          % variable is initialized, but \ProvidesPackage not yet seen
        \else
          \expandafter\ifx\csname PackageInfo\endcsname\relax
            \def\x#1#2{%
              \immediate\write-1{Package #1 Info: #2.}%
            }%
          \else
            \def\x#1#2{\PackageInfo{#1}{#2, stopped}}%
          \fi
          \x{ifluatex}{The package is already loaded}%
          \aftergroup\endinput
        \fi
      \fi
    \endgroup%
    \begingroup\catcode61\catcode48\catcode32=10\relax%
      \catcode13=5 % ^^M
      \endlinechar=13 %
      \catcode35=6 % #
      \catcode39=12 % '
      \catcode40=12 % (
      \catcode41=12 % )
      \catcode44=12 % ,
      \catcode45=12 % -
      \catcode46=12 % .
      \catcode47=12 % /
      \catcode58=12 % :
      \catcode64=11 % @
      \catcode91=12 % [
      \catcode93=12 % ]
      \catcode123=1 % {
      \catcode125=2 % }
      \expandafter\ifx\csname ProvidesPackage\endcsname\relax
        \def\x#1#2#3[#4]{\endgroup
          \immediate\write-1{Package: #3 #4}%
          \xdef#1{#4}%
        }%
      \else
        \def\x#1#2[#3]{\endgroup
          #2[{#3}]%
          \ifx#1\@undefined
            \xdef#1{#3}%
          \fi
          \ifx#1\relax
            \xdef#1{#3}%
          \fi
        }%
      \fi
    \expandafter\x\csname ver@ifluatex.sty\endcsname
    \ProvidesPackage{ifluatex}%
      [2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)]%
    \begingroup\catcode61\catcode48\catcode32=10\relax%
      \catcode13=5 % ^^M
      \endlinechar=13 %
      \catcode123=1 % {
      \catcode125=2 % }
      \catcode64=11 % @
      \def\x{\endgroup
        \expandafter\edef\csname ifluatex@AtEnd\endcsname{%
          \endlinechar=\the\endlinechar\relax
          \catcode13=\the\catcode13\relax
          \catcode32=\the\catcode32\relax
          \catcode35=\the\catcode35\relax
          \catcode61=\the\catcode61\relax
          \catcode64=\the\catcode64\relax
          \catcode123=\the\catcode123\relax
          \catcode125=\the\catcode125\relax
        }%
      }%
    \x\catcode61\catcode48\catcode32=10\relax%
    \catcode13=5 % ^^M
    \endlinechar=13 %
    \catcode35=6 % #
    \catcode64=11 % @
    \catcode123=1 % {
    \catcode125=2 % }
    \def\TMP@EnsureCode#1#2{%
      \edef\ifluatex@AtEnd{%
        \ifluatex@AtEnd
        \catcode#1=\the\catcode#1\relax
      }%
      \catcode#1=#2\relax
    }
    \TMP@EnsureCode{10}{12}% ^^J
    \TMP@EnsureCode{39}{12}% '
    \TMP@EnsureCode{40}{12}% (
    \TMP@EnsureCode{41}{12}% )
    \TMP@EnsureCode{44}{12}% ,
    \TMP@EnsureCode{45}{12}% -
    \TMP@EnsureCode{46}{12}% .
    \TMP@EnsureCode{47}{12}% /
    \TMP@EnsureCode{58}{12}% :
    \TMP@EnsureCode{60}{12}% <
    \TMP@EnsureCode{94}{7}% ^
    \TMP@EnsureCode{96}{12}% `
    \edef\ifluatex@AtEnd{\ifluatex@AtEnd\noexpand\endinput}
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname PackageError\endcsname\relax
      \def\ifluatex@Error#1#2{%
        \begingroup
          \newlinechar=10 %
          \def\MessageBreak{^^J}%
          \edef\x{\errhelp{#2}}%
          \x
          \errmessage{Package ifluatex Error: #1}%
        \endgroup
      }%
    \else
      \def\ifluatex@Error{%
        \PackageError{ifluatex}%
      }%
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\ifx\csname ifluatex\endcsname\relax
      \else
        \edef\i/{\expandafter\string\csname ifluatex\endcsname}%
        \ifluatex@Error{Name clash, \i/ is already defined}{%
          Incompatible versions of \i/ can cause problems,\MessageBreak
          therefore package loading is aborted.%
        }%
        \endgroup
        \expandafter\ifluatex@AtEnd
      \fi%
    \endgroup
    \let\ifluatex\iffalse
    \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\ifx\csname luatexversion\endcsname\relax
    \else
      \expandafter\let\csname ifluatex\expandafter\endcsname
                      \csname iftrue\endcsname
    \fi
    \ifluatex
    \else
      \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
      \expandafter\ifx\csname directlua\endcsname\relax
      \else
        \expandafter\let\csname ifluatex\expandafter\endcsname
                        \csname iftrue\endcsname
        \begingroup
          \newlinechar=10 %
          \endlinechar=\newlinechar%
          \ifnum0%
              \directlua{%
                if tex.enableprimitives then
                  tex.enableprimitives('ifluatex', {'luatexversion'})
                  tex.print('1')
                end
              }%
              \ifx\ifluatexluatexversion\@undefined\else 1\fi %
              =11 %
            \global\let\luatexversion\ifluatexluatexversion%
          \else%
            \ifluatex@Error{%
              Missing \string\luatexversion%
            }{%
              Update LuaTeX.%
            }%
          \fi%
        \endgroup%
      \fi
    \fi
    \ifluatex
      \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
      \expandafter\ifx\csname luatexrevision\endcsname\relax
        \ifnum\luatexversion<36 %
        \else
          \begingroup
            \ifx\luatexrevision\relax
              \let\luatexrevision\@undefined
            \fi
            \newlinechar=10 %
            \endlinechar=\newlinechar%
            \ifcase0%
                \directlua{%
                  if tex.enableprimitives then
                    tex.enableprimitives('ifluatex', {'luatexrevision'})
                  else
                    tex.print('1')
                  end
                }%
                \ifx\ifluatexluatexrevision\@undefined 1\fi%
                \relax%
              \global\let\luatexrevision\ifluatexluatexrevision%
            \fi%
          \endgroup%
        \fi
        \begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
        \expandafter\ifx\csname luatexrevision\endcsname\relax
          \ifluatex@Error{%
            Missing \string\luatexrevision%
          }{%
            Update LuaTeX.%
          }%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \begingroup
      \expandafter\ifx\csname PackageInfo\endcsname\relax
        \def\x#1#2{%
          \immediate\write-1{Package #1 Info: #2.}%
        }%
      \else
        \let\x\PackageInfo
        \expandafter\let\csname on@line\endcsname\empty
      \fi
      \x{ifluatex}{LuaTeX \ifluatex\else not \fi detected}%
    \endgroup
    \ifluatex@AtEnd%
    \endinput
    %%
    %% End of file `ifluatex.sty'.
```

Comment: Make sure that all packages are current. The if-tests have been sorted and this affects more than one package.  Check for updates as user *and* as admin.

Comment: I have a feeling that the `ifluatex` package has been overtaken by the `iftex`(?) package, but don't quote me. I have no idea from your MWE where `\ifluatex` is being used.

Comment: I already tried to delete all packages and still giving error. Never had this problem !!!

Comment: got the same problem! Any solutions?

Comment: Danielsa, Did you format your PC too? What operating system do you use? Enter more characteristics of your problem. Maybe I can find something in common with my problem too

Comment: As Ulrike says, fully update miktex as both admin and user (the miktex console may have two modes). You have have some old versions laying around in user mode. Also try to run "update filename database" (it is in the console)

Comment: @NathanS might also be an idea if you post the full log file, there we can often see if you have something really strange going on.

Comment: Exactly the same problem as above— reinstalled multiple times, updated the packages in both modes (admin and user). Problem still exists.

Comment: @AK16 then we'd like to see a log file from you. If I'm not mistaken, deleting miktex will not deleted the locally installed packages which then gets reused. It is easier to check when we have a log available.

Comment: Guys, I put the complete log file. If you find any errors, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: @AK16 your now deleted log file clearly shows that your system is not up-to-date. Update at least the oberdiek package. Check for updates in the MiKTeX console in user and admin mode.

Comment: @NatanS you are showing a sty not your log file. But the sty shows that your version of the oberdiek package is outdated. So do what I wrote to AK16 above.

Comment: @daleif - Great suggestion. It worked !!!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 20):

Solution found !!!! As proposed by @daleif, I updated the "MikTex Console" in adm and user mode and the problem is over.

Thank you very much @daleif.

Below is the picture showing the console update in adm mode for all to see.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the solution is an update. I starting today facing the same problems you describe and as you can see from the picture everything was from 2018:

[image]

After the update, the problem was solved.